# Python regex to split at word starting with

Tags: python, regex

I know how to search for a word and split a string by it. Example:

```
s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'
r = re.compile('(elit)')  
r.split(s)
# => ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing ', 'elit', ', sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua']
```

How can I do the same, but only knowing the beginning of a word? For example, I'd like to split the string by "consect*" and having it split at the match of "consectetur". Thanks

Comment: It depends on what's a "word" for you. You could match to the next white space: `consect[^\s]*`

Comment: To clarify the answers below, `string.split` will split a string at each occurrence of a given string. `re.split` will split a string at each match of a given regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\w` to match any word character, or `[A-Za-z]` if you want only ASCII alpabetic characters.

```
r = re.compile('(consect\w*)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `(consect\w*)` as the regex:

```
In [3]: import re

In [4]: s = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua'

In [5]: r = re.compile(r'(consect\w*)')  

In [6]: r.split(s)
Out[6]: 
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ',
 'consectetur',
 ' adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua']
```

The `\w*` matches any sequence of alphanumeric characters. You could replace the `\w` with a different character class if your requirements are different.

For further details on Python regular expressions, see [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

use `\w`: Alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]

```
r = re.compile('(consect\w*)')
```

or use `\S`: Non-whitespace characters [^ \t\r\n\v\f]

```
r = re.compile('(consect\S*)')
```